# Windows AD getting hammered by unknown system, need to find out source

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, security

Mostly unmanaged network. Firewall at perimeter, Unifi Wifi. No other real visibility. Win SVR 2016.

Event viewer shows 60k+ events of entirely event id 12294:

"The SAM database was unable to lockout the account of Administrator due to a resource error, such as a hard disk write failure (the specific error code is in the error data) . Accounts are locked after a certain number of bad passwords are provided so please consider resetting the password of the account mentioned above."

My understanding is that this is the event when you attempt to login too many times as admin but AD is set not to lock the admin account. Fine. But it doesn't list the source of the failed login attempt and without any network management tools, netflow/switch mgmt/etc. I'm not sure how to track it down.

Firewall doesn't show any excessive connections, Unifi (Wifi) doesn't show any excessive connections, wireshark on server doesn't show any excessive connections.

Comment: Besides my answer can I provide you with a alternate recommendation?

Comment: PS didn't like some of the syntax from your script. I fixed the first part but that's the extent of my PS abilities. I think maybe $matches is undefined?

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\12294.ps1:15 char:72
+ ... Name = $message -match 'Source Name:\s*(\S+)' | Out-Null; $matches[1]
+                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: I will edit my script with an updated version please try that

Comment: `doesn't list the source of the failed login attempt` the event message is not a failed logon attempt. That would be a 4625 or something similar. This is complaining that the account to be locked could not be locked. Check the error code. Could be a mangled DN due to a conflict CNF object. Check your replication status too.

Comment: You're correct, I think we need to backtrack to the original issue causing the lock attempt. So same situation as above but Event ID is 4776:
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account: PERI  <---changes
Source Workstation:  <-----always blank for users but made-up hostname for admin account
Error Code: 0xC0000064 <---always for users (0xC000006A for admin)

Comment: Going to close this and open another with a more specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Event ID 12294 in the Windows Event Viewer typically corresponds to a NetBT (NetBIOS over TCP/IP) error. It might indicate that a computer is trying to act as a master browser, but it is not winning the election for this role.

Here is a PowerShell script which might help with the analysis of that

```perl
# Define the Event Log parameters
$logName = 'Security'
$eventID = 12294

# Get events with the specified Event ID
$events = Get-WinEvent -LogName $logName -FilterHashtable @{Id=$eventID} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Process each event
foreach ($event in $events) {
    $time = $event.TimeCreated
    $source = $event.ProviderName
    $message = $event.Message

    # Check if message is not null before extracting information
    if ($message -ne $null) {
        # Extract relevant information from the message (adjust as needed)
        $computerName = ($message -split 'Source Name:\s*')[1].Trim()

        # Output information
        Write-Output "Time: $time | Source: $source | Computer: $computerName"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "Time: $time | Source: $source | Computer: Unable to extract computer name"
    }
}
```

Update:
It might be also a good idea to install sysmon with some good rules, so more detailed logging is available which connections are being made and so on.
https://github.com/simeononsecurity/Automate-Sysmon

And create a named administrator account and disable the default Administrator.

Comment: Seems to need it like this: 
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName='System'; Id='12294'} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Still get another error: 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\12294B.ps1:17 char:9
+         $computerName = ($message -split 'Source Name:\s*')[1].Trim()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: No the event is in the security logs right?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on NTLM auditing on your Domain Controller and then use the Windows Logs > NTLM > Operational log to identify the source IP for the NTLM logon attempts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-for-identity/configure-windows-event-collection#configure-ntlm-auditing